# Uploading files via axios to WebApi

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, axios

I'm getting this error when trying to upload a file to webapi

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile'

javascript:

```js
UploadReceivingIssueImages(e) {

    if (!e.target.files || e.target.files.length === 0)
        return;

    let formData = new FormData();


    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('file', e.target.files[i]);

    }

    var vm = this;

    axios.post('../api/receiving/UploadDocReceivingIssueImages?headerId=' + this.SelectedSubIdIdObj.HeaderId,
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }
    ).then(function () {
        vm.getDocReceivingIssueImages();
        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
    }, function (er) {
        alert("Couldn't upload images")
    });
}
```

WebApi Code

```
[HttpPost]
public bool UploadDocReceivingIssueImages([FromUri] int headerId)
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (httpRequest.Files.Count < 1)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("No File Uploaded"),
            ReasonPhrase = "No File Uploaded"
        };
        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
    }

    var dirPath = @"\\dirPath";


    foreach (var f in httpRequest.Files)
    {
        var pf = (System.Web.HttpPostedFile)f;

        pf.SaveAs(dirPath + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + pf.FileName);
    }

    return true;
}
```

the error happens at

```
var pf = (System.Web.HttpPostedFile)f;
```

the `f` object is a string with value 'file'... WHY?!?!
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `f` when the error is thrown?

Comment: type string  = "file"

Comment: So you are trying to convert the value`"file"` to an instance of `System.Web.HttpPostedFile`?

Comment: yes, but why is it string and not System.Web.HttpPostedFile

Comment: @boruchsiper see my answer; you're looping over the list of keys in the `HttpFileCollection`, not the actual files that the entries point to within the collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you enumerate over HttpRequest.PostedFiles you're enumerating over its keys (the names, which are all 'file' based on your JS), not the files:

```cs
        foreach (var key in httpRequest.Files)
        {
            var pf = httpRequest.Files[key]; // implicit cast to HttpPostedFile

            pf.SaveAs(dirPath + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + pf.FileName);
        }
```

EDIT TO ADD:

With that said, you'll need to update your JS to use unique names in `FormData` or else you'll only be able to read one file out of your `HttpContext`'s `HttpFileCollection`:

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('file' + i, e.target.files[i]);

    }
```

See [HttpFileCollection on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpfilecollection?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston it was actually your comment that gave me the hunch. Then I remembered dealing with a similar issue on my own file uploading implementation in .NET